# Replacing "Other - Write in" with written in text in survey data with Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-cleaning, survey

I have a large set of survey response data that I'm having trouble cleaning.

At the beginning of the survey, respondents select a group (color, in this example), and were conditionally shown the same question (in this example, "Rank your favorite three fruits out of this list, or write in another fruit"), but conditional on the color they chose, they were shown different lists of fruits to choose from.

Originally, the data looked something like this. There's a column for every combination of color and answer choice, with the value being the rank they gave that answer choice, and an "other" column with a text response they wrote in if they ranked "other" as one of their choices:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 8
   responseid color   red_q1_a  red_q1_b  red_q1_c  red_q1_other  red_q1_other_answer blue_q1_a
        <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>    <chr>                   <dbl>
 1         34 red           2        1       NA            3    "Pomegranates"             NA
 2         35 blue         NA       NA       NA           NA    NA                          1
 3         36 green        NA       NA       NA           NA    NA                         NA
 4         37 purple       NA       NA       NA           NA    NA                         NA
 5         38 red           1       NA        3            2    "Watermelon"               NA
 6         39 green        NA       NA       NA           NA    NA                         NA
 7         40 purple       NA       NA       NA           NA    NA                         NA
 8         41 blue         NA       NA       NA           NA    NA                         NA
 9         42 blue         NA       NA       NA           NA    NA                          2
10         43 green        NA       NA       NA           NA    NA                         NA
11         44 red           1        3        2           NA    NA                         NA
```

I managed to clean the data to the point that it looks something like this, for the first question:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 6
   responseid color  q1_first_choice   q1_second_choice   q1_third_choice   q1_other_answer
        <dbl> <chr>  <chr>             <chr>              <chr>             <chr>          
 1         34 red    q1_red_b           q1_red_a            q1_red_other       "Pomegranate"    
 2         35 blue   q1_blue_a          q1_blue_c           q1_blue_b          NA             
 3         36 green  q1_green_other     q1_green_b          q1_green_a         "Tangerine"      
 4         37 purple q1_purple_b        q1_purple_a         q1_purple_c        NA             
 5         38 red    q1_red_a           q1_red_other        q1_red_c           "Watermelon"     
 6         39 green  q1_green_a         q1_green_c          q1_green_b         NA             
 7         40 purple q1_purple_b        q1_purple_a         q1_purple_c        NA             
 8         41 blue   q1_blue_c          q1_blue_a           q1_blue_other      "Blueberries"    
 9         42 blue   q1_blue_a          q1_blue_c           q1_blue_b          NA             
10         43 green  q1_green_c         q1_green_b          q1_green_a         NA             
11         44 red    q1_red_b           q1_red_a            q1_red_c           NA
```

I have two additional steps I'd like to take, and I'm not sure how to go about them efficiently. First, I'd like to replace any ranked choice that's an "other" option with the write-in text value, so it would look like this:

```
   responseid color q1_first_choice    q1_second_choice    q1_third_choice 
          34 red    q1_red_b           q1_red_a            "Pomegranate"    
          35 blue   q1_blue_c          q1_blue_a           q1_blue_b          
          36 green  "Tangerine"        q1_green_b          q1_green_a         
          37 purple q1_purple_b        q1_purple_a         q1_purple_c        
          38 red    q1_red_a           "Watermelon"        q1_red_c           
          39 green  q1_green_a         q1_green_c          q1_green_b                      
          40 purple q1_purple_b        q1_purple_a         q1_purple_c                     
          41 blue   q1_blue_c          q1_blue_b           "Blueberries"    
          42 blue   q1_blue_a          q1_blue_c           q1_blue_b                       
          43 green  q1_green_c         q1_green_b          q1_green_a                      
          44 red    q1_red_b           q1_red_a            q1_red_c
```

I'm having trouble trying to use an efficient ifelse or case_when for this - I want a function that says, for all the values in columns q1_first_choice:q1_third_choice, if they contain the string "other", replace them with the value in column q1_other_answer in that row.

Then finally, I want to replace the answer codes ("q1_blue_c", etc) with their actual values. I'm thinking this could be straightforward enough with a case_when function, but is there an efficient way to apply that transformation to multiple rows, for a very long list of cases? I do have a codebook for the survey linking all the variable names to their actual answer choice (ie, q1_red_a is "Apple", q1_red_b is "Banana", etc, through the hundreds of choices). Is there a good way to store that list as some kind of object in R, and set up the ifelse/case_when statement to refer to that, rather than typing out the whole list inside the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you ask your second question as a separate question? It's best to keep each question on its own so that it's easier for future readers to find solutions to each specific problem.

For the first problem, the idea is to use `if_else()` where if the word "other" is included (using `str_detect()`), replace with `q1_other_answer`, else leave as is. Then apply that across the variables you want using `mutate_at()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

mydf <- tribble(
~responseid, ~color,  ~q1_first_choice,   ~q1_second_choice,   ~q1_third_choice,   ~q1_other_answer,
34, "red   " , "q1_red_b     "  ,    "q1_red_a    "    ,    "q1_red_other "   ,   "Pomegranate"    ,
35, "blue  " , "q1_blue_a    "  ,    "q1_blue_c   "    ,    "q1_blue_b    "   ,   NA             ,
36, "green " , "q1_green_other" ,    "q1_green_b  "    ,    "q1_green_a   "   ,   "Tangerine"      ,
37, "purple" , "q1_purple_b  "  ,    "q1_purple_a "    ,    "q1_purple_c  "   ,   NA             ,
38, "red   " , "q1_red_a     "  ,    "q1_red_other"    ,    "q1_red_c     "   ,   "Watermelon"     ,
39, "green " , "q1_green_a   "  ,    "q1_green_c  "    ,    "q1_green_b   "   ,   NA             ,
40, "purple" , "q1_purple_b  "  ,    "q1_purple_a "    ,    "q1_purple_c  "   ,   NA             ,
41, "blue  " , "q1_blue_c    "  ,    "q1_blue_a   "    ,    "q1_blue_other"   ,   "Blueberries"    ,
42, "blue  " , "q1_blue_a    "  ,    "q1_blue_c   "    ,    "q1_blue_b    "   ,   NA             ,
43, "green " , "q1_green_c   "  ,    "q1_green_b  "    ,    "q1_green_a   "   ,   NA             ,
44, "red   " , "q1_red_b     "  ,    "q1_red_a    "    ,    "q1_red_c     "   ,   NA       
) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, str_trim)

mutate_at(mydf, vars(ends_with("choice")), ~ if_else(str_detect(., "other"), q1_other_answer, .))

# A tibble: 11 x 6
   responseid color  q1_first_choice q1_second_choice q1_third_choice q1_other_answer
        <dbl> <chr>  <chr>           <chr>            <chr>           <chr>          
 1         34 red    q1_red_b        q1_red_a         Pomegranate     Pomegranate    
 2         35 blue   q1_blue_a       q1_blue_c        q1_blue_b       NA             
 3         36 green  Tangerine       q1_green_b       q1_green_a      Tangerine      
 4         37 purple q1_purple_b     q1_purple_a      q1_purple_c     NA             
 5         38 red    q1_red_a        Watermelon       q1_red_c        Watermelon     
 6         39 green  q1_green_a      q1_green_c       q1_green_b      NA             
 7         40 purple q1_purple_b     q1_purple_a      q1_purple_c     NA             
 8         41 blue   q1_blue_c       q1_blue_a        Blueberries     Blueberries    
 9         42 blue   q1_blue_a       q1_blue_c        q1_blue_b       NA             
10         43 green  q1_green_c      q1_green_b       q1_green_a      NA             
11         44 red    q1_red_b        q1_red_a         q1_red_c        NA
```

Comment: Just to note that with `dplyr 1.0.0` coming out soon this would also be tackled using `mutate` and `across`

Comment: Yes. My understanding though is that scoped variants will remain available for a few years still, so this answer should still be applicable for the next little while.